# ReactiveKit Subject "unobserveNext" Method?

Tags: swift, reactivekit

ReactiveKit documentation [says](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit#subjects):

> How do we use such subject?
>
> let name = Subject()
>
> name.observeNext { name in print("Hi (name)!") }

Is there kind of "unobserveNext" Method?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? By calling dispose you can make unsubscribe.

```
let dispose = name.observeNext { name in print("Hi (name)!") }
dispose.dispose();
```